# Как переписать линуксовые bash под mac os?

Tags: mac, git-bash

Как прописать такое на макось?

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y gcc g++ make git cmake cmake-gui qt5-qmake qt5-default libqt5serialport5-dev
sudo apt install -y libudev-dev libusb-dev libfox-1.6-dev autotools-dev autoconf automake libtool libsfml*

git submodule init
git submodule update

cd hidapi
./bootstrap
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
cd ../

chmod +x compile_PoolsideGUI.sh
./compile_PoolsideGUI.sh
```

Comment: если коротко то никак. apt - установщик пакетов debian, но это еще половина дела. как в ваших макосях будут зваться указанные пакеты одному богу известно

Comment: если открыть репозиторий, где это взято - https://github.com/hidronautics/PoolsideGUI , то там явно видно, что требуется Ubuntu 20.04 и выше. Макось никак не подходит под эти требования. Поэтому, если оно сильно нужно - то остается только портировать ручками